# Converting Large 200mb csv file to Parquet file using Apache spark

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, parquet

I am trying to convert csv file to Parquet file using Apache spark, for small csv it is working quite well but for huge csv it Job just keep going on it never stops and it is giving below error, I am not sure what wrong am I doing or what configuration I have to add. Please help

```
    20:02:27.232 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3)] DEBUG org.apache.parquet.crypto.EncryptionPropertiesFactory - EncryptionPropertiesFactory is not configured - name not found in hadoop config
20:02:27.232 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3)] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem - NativeIO.createDirectoryWithMode error, path = D:\bigcsv\test1.parquet\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_202204252002273263990563677151010_0002_m_000000_3, mode = 755
org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode(NativeIO.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
```

and my code is as below:

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("csv2parquet")
            .master("local")
            .getOrCreate();

 final String dir = "D:/bigcsv/Data.csv";

    Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv(dir);
    final String parquetFile = "D:/bigcsv/test1.parquet";
    final String codec = "parquet";

  // For mode I also tried "overwrite" but it's still not working
ds.write().option("compression", "gzip").mode("append").format(codec).save(parquetFile);
    spark.stop();
```

After adding below line it started working but for 200mb file it took too much time how to reduce it.

```
ds.write().option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000).option("compression", "gzip").mode("overwrite").format(codec).save(parquetFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to remove the ".parquet" from the `parquetFile`.

e.g change `parquetFile` to `D:/bigcsv/parquets/`.
also if you want only 1 parquet file to be written instead of multiple you should use `.coalesce(1)` but it will take more time to write it.